# How to convert html elements and canvas to PDF together?

Tags: javascript, pdf, canvas, jspdf, html2canvas

I have a canvas which displays a lot of stuff, but above it there are lots of html elements as well

When I try to use html2canvas lib with jsPdf all together I don't have html elements in the pdf at all, only just several of them.

here is the code:

```
html2canvas(document.body).then((canvas) => {
 const imgData = canvas.toDataUrl('image/png');
 const imgWidth = (canvas.width * 20) / 120;
 const imgHeight = (canvas.height * 20) / 120;
 const pdf = new jsPDF("p", "mm", "a4");

 pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 0, 0, imgWidth, imgHeight);
 pdf.save('test.pdf');
});
```

btw the same happens if I don't use jsPDF at all, html2canvas takes canvas elements only :(

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you can check this website maybe can help you to break problem :
https://phppot.com/php/converting-html-into-multi-page-pdf-using-javascript-library/